# Shake animation não para?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Eu tenho um problema com o shake animation, uma vez que ele começa, não consigo fazê-lo parar

```
var shakeit = null;
function abre(a){
    clearInterval(shakeit);
}
function fecha(){
    var shakeit = setInterval(function(){
        $(".left_noti2").effect("shake",{direction:"up", distance:"5", times: "2"});
    }, 3000);
}
```

Uma vez que eu carregue no botão para fechar a div, eu gostaria que o botão ela tivesse o efeito shake, mas mal abrisse de novo, gostaria que ela (função) parasse, mas o código que tenho não está a resultar, existe alguma solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está na linha `var shakeit = setInterval(function(){`, onde você está definindo uma variável `shakeit` dentro do escopo da função `fecha()`, sendo assim a função `abre()` não tem acesso.

Segue o trecho funcionando:

```js
var shakeit = null;

function abre() {
  clearInterval(shakeit);
}

function fecha() {
  shakeit = setInterval(function() {
    $(".left_noti2").effect("shake", {
      direction: "up",
      distance: "5",
      times: "2"
    });
  }, 3000);
}

$('#btnAbre').click(function() {
  abre();
});

$('#btnFecha').click(function() {
  fecha();
});
```

```css
.left_noti2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnAbre">Parar</button>
<button type="button" id="btnFecha">Agitar</button>

<div class="left_noti2"></div>
```